# I need to retrieve the index(number 1) information in mongodb compass

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I just need to query all information of the doctor in the first index.

[Here is my sample XML data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqRvQ.png)
[Here is my sample JSON data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s93ei.png)
Both XML and JSON data are same. I just converted the XML to JSON format.
I have more documents like this.

[I tried this query in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abkw8.png)
this query showing all information but I just need first doctors information.
I also tried in command prompt.[Here is the query done in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDlAF.png)

Here is my sample JSON code block: but I have more similar documents

```
{
    "doctors": {
        "doctor":[
            {
                "ssn": "257-79-xxxx",
                "name": "Mavis Bxx",
                "address": "xxxx Rusk Drive",
                "country": "France",
                "email": "",
                "phone": "",
                "patients": {
                    "patient": [
                        {
                            "gender": "Male",
                            "name": "Itch xxxx",
                            "address": "xx Cottonwood Avenue",
                            "revenue": "254",
                            "_country": "Spain",
                            "_id": "27"
                        },
                        {
                            "gender": "Male",
                            "name": "Damon xxxxx",
                            "address": "xx David Trail",
                            "revenue": "370",
                            "_country": "Germany",
                            "_id": "21"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "_id": "6"
            },
            {
                "ssn": "179-45-xxxx",
                "name": "Tobie Conxxxx",
                "address": "x Comanche Center",
                "country": "Spain",
                "email": "tconringh@xxx.xxx",
                "phone": "+86 998 262 xxxx",
                "patients": {
                    "patient": {
                        "gender": "Male",
                        "name": "Vergil Tome",
                        "address": "x Melody Drive",
                        "revenue": "254",
                        "_country": "Germany",
                        "_id": "15"
                    }
                },
                "_id": "18"
            },
            {
                "ssn": "777-59-xxxx",
                "name": "Gertrud Macxxxx",
                "address": "x Buell Drive",
                "country": "USA",
                "email": "gmaclaig2@xxx.com",
                "phone": "+62 975 394 xxxx",
                "patients": {
                    "patient": [
                        {
                            "gender": "Non-binary",
                            "name": "Dre Skxxxx",
                            "address": "x Becker Circle",
                            "revenue": "400",
                            "_country": "Germany",
                            "_id": "20"
                        },
                        {
                            "gender": "Female",
                            "name": "Arleyne Lestxxxx",
                            "address": "xx Farragut Court",
                            "revenue": "225",
                            "_country": "France",
                            "_id": "22"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "_id": "3"
            }
```

Comment: Instead of providing links, add the sample data and queries you tried, to the question.

Comment: ... in a code block please, rather than an image.

Comment: ... and this data should absolutely be redacted if the information is real!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needs to change your collect data format. Your current format is single big size data. Not a quarriable format.

So

From current format

```
{
    "doctors": {
        "docker": [
            {
                ...
                "patients": {
                    "patient": [
                        {
                            ...
                        },
                        {
                            ...
                        }
                    ]
                },
            },
            {
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

To this format

```
[
    {
        ...
        "patients": [
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

Test JSON

```
[
    {
        "ssn": "2xx-7x-4xxx",
        "name": "Mavis Bxxxed",
        "address": "9xxx Rusk Drive",
        "country": "France",
        "email": "",
        "phone": "",
        "patients": [
            {
                "gender": "Male",
                "name": "Itch Txxx",
                "address": "5xx Cottonwood Avenue",
                "revenue": "25x",
                "_country": "Spain",
                "_id": "27"
            },
            {
                "gender": "Male",
                "name": "Damon Wxxx",
                "address": "09xx Dxxxx Trail",
                "revenue": "370",
                "_country": "Germany",
                "_id": "21"
            }
        ],
        "_id": "6"
    },
    {
        "ssn": "19-45-xxxx",
        "name": "Tobie Coxxxx",
        "address": "8x Comxxxx Center",
        "country": "Spain",
        "email": "tconxxxxx@usa.gov",
        "phone": "",
        "patients": [
            {
                "gender": "Male",
                "name": "Some one",
                "address": "1 Mexxxx Drive",
                "revenue": "254",
                "_country": "Germany",
                "_id": "15"
            }
        ],
        "_id": "18"
    }
]
```

In Compass View after `add data` upper data
[image]

#### Find doctor by name query

```
{ name: "Mavis Bxxxed" }
```

[image]

#### Find doctor by patient name

```
{ "patients.name": "Some one" }
```

[image]

If same search with this query

```
{ "patients.name": "Itch Txxx" }
OR
{ "patients.name": "Damon Wxxx" }
```

will same result to find the first docker (Mavis Bxxxed)
Due to it's patients start `[` and end `]`. it is array type a single size of data.

You can filter by project option

```
  {
    patients: {
      $filter:
      {
          input: "$patients",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$patient.name", "Itch Txxx"] },
          as: "patient"
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

OR shows only address

```
{ "patients.address" : 1 }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. and if I want to retrieve only the address of the patients by providing the patients name, is that possible to do?

Comment: @harikishoreV , I updated my answer with two options but no idea filter and shows address option AND condition. Can you vote me? It will encourage me to answer.